# Unknown user 119 when I type ps

Tags: users, process, user-space

when I typed

```
    ps -aux
```

i recived

```
   (...)
    root      2158  0.3  0.1  43860  6028 ?        Sl   Jan18   0:36 Passenger spawn server       
    119       2037  0.0  0.6  59152 26208 ?        S    Jan18   0:08 /usr/sbin/tor
   (...)
```

My question is what is this magic tor in my sbin and what is 119 user? I have only one proces from it and it name is tor..

Comment: You are entering the command wrong, it should not have the `-` character, should be just `ps aux`.

Comment: @Lucio Well, you may be right, but unless a user `x` exists, this gracefully falls back to the correct `ps aux`. See the manpage of `ps(1)` which explains this topic completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User id 119 can't be resolved to a name in your case. Did you remove it without stopping all processes owned by it?

Apparently you're running [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) on that server.

There's nothing much more to tell from the information you provided. Assuming you're the administrator you should remember installing Tor on it.